# Python Terminal Text Output Formatting

Tags: python, numpy, terminal, formatting, output

I have a python program that outputs a few numpy matricies and some other information to my terminal in this fashion:
[image: Terminal output]

Currently, to view the data, I follow this order:

1. Print data
2. Clear Screen
3. Re print (and repeat)

However, this is really inefficient. What I would like to be able to do is to see the numbers changing as the program runs, but without the overhead of screen clearing. Is there a way I can format my output using native python so that I won't have to to this expensive operation? The idea is I can have something that works like htop (or similar formatted terminal programs, such as [cmus](http://www.tuxarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/cmus.jpg)).

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done without using a library like `curses`  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html  Otherwise you're at the mercy of stdout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why clearing the screen is such an expense? The terminal has, most likely, a buffer of fixed size which is overwritten as older lines "scroll up". Rewriting the output may take a few ms (or more, depends on how big it is). 
If the output is really massive, consider a different approach, e.g. slice your matrices and only output what changed or use a plot to inspect your data (hint: matrices can be displayed as images).
If you really need a "fixed" display on a terminal, then `curses` module is the way to go, but then your output cannot be that big, otherwise it would not fit a terminal window anyway. If you need to implement scrolling, then consider moving to a graphical user interface.

Comment: On my server (where the script is running), there is a measurable slowdown in the process for unknown reasons. In addition, clearing the screen, causes a lot of flickering, making any data hard to read (mostly for changes)

Comment: Do the numbers change very frequently? Would refreshing the display only when something changes work? If not, you really need `curses`.

Comment: Most numbers stay constant, and the script already only prints when certain changes are met, so the change idea is already there. Looks like it's going to be `curses` for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `watch` shell command

if it is a python script or can be trasformed in an unique python script

watch -n 1 'python xxx.py'

1 is the refresh time

`-d` highlight changes between updates

Comment: I had considered this, but I don't know the exact refresh rate of my program, the `-d` option is quite good though!

Comment: do you need more faster than 1 sec?
or the script print other if is not ready?